# Using XSLT extract xpath of all text nodes with value from any xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml:

```
<root>
 <child attrib1="1">
  <subChild>
   <name>subChild1</name>
  </subChild>
 </child>
 <child attrib1="2>
  <subChild2>
   <name>subChild2</name>
  </subChild2>
 </child>
```

I want xslt to generate o/p as follows i.e. xpath and its value:

1. /root/child[@attrib1="1]/subChild/name="subChild1"
2. /root/child[@attrib1="2]/subChild2/name="subChild2"

Comment: For which nodes exactly do you want to generate a path expression? What happened if you had more than one`<child attrib1="1"><subChild><name>foo</name></subChild></child>` elements? You paths don't seem to help to uniquely identify elements. Also, which version of XSLT do you use? XPath 3 has https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-path which is certainly generating a more generic and more precise path for the case of all the complications of namespaces and duplicates.

Comment: As so often happens, one single example of an input and a corresponding output does not constitute a specification.

Comment: apologies, i corrected the expected o/p in above. In general, i want to generate xpath for all text nodes in a given xml using xslt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, your question is not entirely clear. Try something like this as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//text()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::*"/>
        <xsl:text>="</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>"&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::*"/>
    <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:text>[@</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text>="</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>"]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks michael.hor257k above xslt works and generates desired result ! I am very much new to xslt, tried an alternate xslt as mentioned in below anwser referring to other posts. Which is best source to learn/explore programming using xslt ? w3schools provided very basic intro, where can i learn above advanced programming/functions in xslt ?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to other posts I tried below xslt, it generates the expected output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vApos">'</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <xsl:if test="not(*)">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor-or-self::*" mode="path"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="concat('=',$vApos,.,$vApos)"/>
     <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="path">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',name())"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="path"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*" mode="path">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('[@',name(), '=',$vApos,.,$vApos,']')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample input xml:

```
<root id='1'>
    <elemA>one</elemA>
    <elemA attribute1='first' attribute2='second'>two</elemA>
    <elemB attribute='1'>three</elemB>
    <elemA >four</elemA>
    <elemC attribute='c'>
        <elemB attribute='2'>five</elemB>
        <elemB attribute='3'>five</elemB>
    </elemC>
</root>
```

Output:

```
/root[@id='1']/elemA='one'
/root[@id='1']/elemA[@attribute1='first'][@attribute2='second']='two'
/root[@id='1']/elemB[@attribute='1']='three'
/root[@id='1']/elemA='four'
/root[@id='1']/elemC[@attribute='c']/elemB[@attribute='2']='five'
/root[@id='1']/elemC[@attribute='c']/elemB[@attribute='3']='five'
```